# Configuring TsVector with one to many relation

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a `PostgreSQL` server and a project with `EF Core 6`.

I have configured the Fulltext Search, but i have a problem in one specific case.

I need to include fields from linked table (one-to-many) in index. So, my table `Foo` have many `Bar` items, and i want to include `Bar.Car` into `Foo` fulltext index.

```
var queryable = _dbContext.Foos
.Include(x => x.Car)
.Include(x => x.Items).ThenInclude(x => x.Car)
.AsNoTracking()
.Select(x => new SearchPreQuery
{
 Id = x.Id,
 Value = string.Join(" ", x.Car.Name, x.Number, string.Join(" ", x.Items.Select(x => x.Car.Name))).ToLower()
});        
queryable.InsertFromQuery(typeof(FooSearch), x => new FooSearch { Id = x.Id, SearchVector = EF.Functions.ToTsVector(x.Value) });
```

this code works only if i don't include part with `Items` field. When they are present in the code, i have a strange error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')'` in `String.Substring` method (I think it is in the `EF.Function.ToTsVector`? I can't figure out by call stack)

I also tried to use `SelectMany` like this:

```
.Select(x => new SearchPreQuery
{
 Id = x.Id,
 Value = string.Join(" ", x.Car.Name, x.Number, x.Items.SelectMany(x => x.Car.Name)).ToLower()
 });
```

but got the error `x.Car.Name could not be translated`